# Add headers to a request in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, header

I'm using Rails 3.2.1 to make an HTTP Post.

I need to add `X-FORWARDED` FOR to the header.  How do I do that in Rails?

Code:

```
post_data = {
  "username" => tabuser
}

response = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse("http://<my php file>"), post_data)
```

Comment: These net::http examples might be helpful? https://github.com/augustl/net-http-cheat-sheet/blob/master/headers.rb

Comment: Thanks! If you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: added comment as the answer - Cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be set on the request object:

```
request = Post.new(url)
request.form_data = params
request['X-Forwarded-For'] = '203.0.113.195'
request.start(url.hostname, url.port,
        :use_ssl => url.scheme == 'https' ) {|http|
    http.request(request) }
```

See these Net::HTTP examples:

https://github.com/augustl/net-http-cheat-sheet/blob/master/headers.rb

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. You may want to have actual code on how to add headers within the body of the answer.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - my answer is from over 5 years ago. While not perfect it is what it is.

Answer (score 15):

I find this more readable

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

url = URI.parse("http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp")

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
req.add_field("X-Forwarded-For", "0.0.0.0")
req.add_field("Accept", "*/*")

res = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port).start do |http|
  http.request(req)
end

puts res.body
```

stolen from http://www.dzone.com/snippets/send-custom-headers-rub

HOWEVER !!

if you want to send 'Accept' header (`Accept: application/json`) to Rails application, you cannot do:

`req.add_field("Accept", "application/json")`

but do:

`req['Accept'] = 'application/json'`

The reason for this that Rails ignores the Accept header when it contains “,/” or “/,” and returns HTML (which `add_field` adds). This is due to really old browsers sending incorrect "Accept" headers.

Answer (score 10):

Both answers are ok, but I would add one important thing. If you are using https you must add line that you use ssl:

```
url = URI.parse('https://someurl.com')
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.request_uri)
req["header_name"] = header
response = http.request(req)
```

Without this use_ssl you will get 'EOFError (end of file reached)'.

Comment: This is critical if ssl is required because you can otherwise build a perfect request and still get a '400 Bad Request' response.

Answer (score 1):

The original question was for an **http post** which is what I was looking for. I'm going to include this solution for others who may be looking:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI.parse("http://<my php file>")

header = {'X-Forwarded-For': '0.0.0.0'}

# Create the HTTP objects
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, header)

# Send the request
response = http.request(request)
```